# Display the data from the sql query route and show in the blade

Tags: laravel, sqlite

How can I display the data that I get from the sql query route and show in the blade not using the controller?

```
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-bottom">
    <div class="w3-quarter">
        <div class="w3-container w3-red w3-padding-16">
            <div class="w3-left">
                <i class="fa fa-comment w3-xxxlarge"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-right">
                @foreach ($vehicleCount as $data)
                    <h3>{{$data}}</h3>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="w3-clear"></div>
            <h4>Total Vehicles</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    $sql="select count(id) from vehicle  ";
    $quesryVeh=DB::select($sql);
    // $data1= gettype( $quesryVeh);
   
    // dd($data);
    return view('/dashboard')->with('vehicleCount',$quesryVeh);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily retrieve aggregate values like `count` by:

```
DB::table('users')->count();
```

Route :

```
Route::get('dashboard', function () {
    $quesryVeh = DB::table('users')->count();

    return view('dashboard', ['vehicleCount' => $quesryVeh]);
});
```

View :

```
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-bottom">
    <div class="w3-quarter">
        <div class="w3-container w3-red w3-padding-16">
            <div class="w3-left">
                <i class="fa fa-comment w3-xxxlarge"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-right">
                <h3>{{ $vehicleCount }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-clear"></div>
            <h4>Total Vehicles</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use :

```
@foreach ($vehicleCount as $data)
    <h3>{{ $data->yourColumnName }}</h3>
@endforeach
```

Comment: $sql="select count(id) from vehicle  ";
    $quesryVeh=DB::select($sql); this is my query and i dont know the column name ?

Comment: the query works fine in the route and bring the data as well but i dont know how to display at the blade view